# IEnumerable property creation in Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to create a property of type `IEnumerable<AnotherDynamicType>` using `Reflection.Emit`.

I have a helper method that adds properties fine, accepting a Type as input:

```
public void AddProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type type) 
{
    ....
}
```

This can be called in this manner:

```
AddProperty(typeBuilder,"MyPropertyName",typeof(string));
```

However now I wish to add a property to the class:

```
public IEnumerable<AnotherDynamicType> MyList {get;set;}
```

How do I define the "Type" of this property for the call, given that the target `AnotherDynamicType` is also dynamically created?

The following doesn't compile:

```
AddProperty(typeBuilder,"MyPropertyName",typeof(IEnumerable<typeof(anotherDynamicType)>));
```

Comment: Use `typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(anotherDynamicType))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var anotherTypeEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                            .MakeGenericType(anotherDynamicType);
```

Comment: I suspect `anotherDynamicType` is a `Type`, in which case you need to drop the `.GetType()`.

Comment: Second one did the trick, as "anotherDynamicType" is the target TypeBuilder class